# rails , prototype and :afterFinish callback question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

why does this work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mycallback = function() {
      $('user_session_username').focus();
     };
</script>

page.visual_effect :appear, 'user-response', :afterFinish => "mycallback"
```

whereas neither of the below statements work

```
page.visual_effect :appear, 'user-response', :afterFinish => "$('user_session_username').focus()"
```

or

```
page.visual_effect :appear, 'user-response', :afterFinish => "$('user_session_username').focus"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
page.visual_effect :appear, 'user-response', :afterFinish => "function(){$('user_session_username').focus()}"
```

Note:
`link_to_function` will work for Rails 2.x but not in Rails 3.x. [More info on this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/3/2/unobtrusive-yet-explicit).